# change 12 cells in row based on 1 word in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to change the color of A1 - L1. Based on a word in cell F1
If F1 finds the word "Inspection" in the phrase "*Chev 2500 Inspection*" in that cell it would fill A1-L1 green.

Or if it finds the word Repair in the phrase in that cell then it would change A1-L1 to purple.

I tried a formula in conditional formatting that didn't do what I wanted

Formula:

```
=$F$1="Inspection"  Applies to: =$A$1:$L$1
```

But that changes if cell F1 only has the word "Inspection", not if it contains the word in a phrase.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution consist in using a formula to extract the word "Inspection" from A1-L1 and put it in another row. Then you can use the conditional formatting by looking for that specific word.
You can do the same with the word "repair" in another row, then decide which priority criteria to apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can have the conditional formatting formula use the search function like this

[image: screenshot showing formula in conditional fomatting]

so you'd would want

```
=IF(SEARCH("inspection",$F$1),TRUE,FALSE)  Applies to: =$A$1:$L$1
```